# Why choose "string".charAt(0) over "string"[0]?

Tags: javascript, string, char, indexing

The outputs for the two are the same. 
I prefer `"string"[0]` because it's shorter, but when would you want to use `charAt()` instead?

Answer (score 4):

`string[0]` is not supported by IE7.